# How to install MySQLdb with python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

I'm trying to connect to mySQL with python. From what I understand you need to have MySQLdb which is some python connector module. My first problem was not having the right version of the mySQLdb. It can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python). Then I am supposed to open a command line window and navigate to the path of the file I just downloaded (after unzipping) and type`python setup.py build` This then gave me an error saying that I needed to downloaded setup tools. Setup tools apparently was discontinued after python 2.6 or 7. Now we are supposed to use distribute, which I found [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#installation-instructions), as a replacement. I did that and now when I try to make my build call It spits out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_windows import get_config
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL-python-1.2.3\setup_windows.py", line 46
    print """You shouldn't be running this directly; it is used by setip.py."""

Syntax Error: invalid syntax
```

I need someone to hold my hand and walk me through how to get this setup. I've spent 6 hours on google trying to figure it out. (I read in more than one place that it is a difficult install but very worth it. I hope they're right.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further googling I don't think that using mysqldb or whatever is the best solution. I found this page: http://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL 
I decided to give the mysql connector/python a try. It seems pretty straightforward with no crazy installs.

Comment: +1 needed a simple way to interface to Mysql from python 3.x in Windows. The mysql connector/python did the trick easily without any installation needed.

Comment: If you want to interface with django you need the mySQLdb. I had to go back to python 2.7 to get everything to fit together properly as django isn't yet compatible with python 3.x

Answer (score 4):

Please note that you have to have `curl` installed. You can grab it from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).
Assuming `python.exe` command starts python3 on your machine.

Steps:

1. Download `distribute_setup.py` from `python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py`‎ to upgrade setuptools.
2. Execute the following command to upgrade setuptools for your local python3:

   > python.exe distribute_setup.py
3. Download and install the `pymysql` driver:

   > curl -L https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/tarball/pymysql-0.6 | tar xz
   >   cd PyMySQL-PyMySQL-7c86923/
   >   sudo python3 setup.py install
4. Download and install MySQLdb driver for python3

   > git clone https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3.git
   >   cd MySQL-for-Python-3/
   >   python3 setup.py install
5. To check open python interpreter via `python.exe` command and execute:

   > import pymysql
   >   import MySQLdb

If everything went ok - then both lines should not fail.

Comment: It's a little bit hard to read and understand the answer. Please format it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get MySQLdb to work with Python 3 either, so I installed the [MySQL/Connector module](https://launchpad.net/myconnpy). It's been workin' like a charm & it was a simple install. I was a complete Python newbie at the time, so unless I'm a genius then it's pretty easy to install for anyone.

Comment: If you want to use Python with django you need to be on version 2.7. It's a bit of a pain to install because they force you to use pythondb but after that you see the payoff.