# How to access MySQL from python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I've always used Xampp for db/ server purposes. I'm trying to use the same with my Python project but cannot seem to get it to work.

Error from Python Shell

```
import MySQLdb
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I've been all around but nothing seems to work. I'm on windows 7, Python 3.3.

Please someone advise. Links that would resolve this quick will be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
Please note that it seems MySQL-python does not support python3

Comment: did u install mysqldb library

Comment: Hi @sundar nataraj. It seems MySQL-python does not support python3. Any ideas around this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031151/how-to-install-mysqldb-with-python-3-2 .see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/8r_RVmUe5ys
Here is some connectors that can be used for mysql in Python 3.x:

1. https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3 / https://github.com/clelland/MySQL-for-Python-3
2. http://www.pymysql.org/
3. https://github.com/farcepest/moist
4. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python/1.0.9

Comment: Thanks to you I finally got it working. I still think that the question is quite important, despite the down-vote. Thanks again. A lot

Answer (score 0):

`pip install MySQL-python`

Run this in your Windows console or Linux terminal, and this problem should disappear.

Comment: Hi @Samba. It seems MySQL-python does not support python3. Any ideas around this?