# Errors when migrate command is used to create database tables

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to learn Django and installed it on my system. I have Xubuntu 14.04 and my python version is 3.4.0 also 2.7.6. I get lots of error messages when I executed `python3 manage.py migrate` (I used `python3` because 2.7.6 version is taken by default.)

The first and last lines of errors are this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql  /base.py", line 15, in <module>
import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 18, in <module>
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

I installed all kinds of packages related to python and mysql. Still I haven't been able to fix this problem. The last error line tells my that I don't have module named MySQLdb but that module is not supported in python3, am I right? So as an alternative I have installed `mysqlclient` as the official documentation instructed. Still I get these error messages. How can I solve this?

My `settings.py` file is like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',        
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'NAME': 'django_example',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': '729183456'
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031151/how-to-install-mysqldb-with-python-3-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try running this command.
mysql is definitely supported.

pip install MySQL-python